# generated-snippet not creating in target folder

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I am add spring restdocs in existing spring boot project but unfortunately `generated-snippet` folder not creating in `target` folder when i run `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean` and `mvn install` or `mvn clean test`. Bellow is my pom configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>ppi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ppi</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>s
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.357</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.12</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                </directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**TestCases class:**

```
package com.ppi.customer

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
import org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation
import org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.preprocessResponse
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.prettyPrint
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class CustomerTest {
    @Rule
    public final JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private JsonSlurper jsonSlurper

    private RestDocumentationResultHandler document

    CustomerTest() {
        jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        this.document = document(
                "{class-name}/{method-name}",
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())
        )

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .alwaysDo(document)
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    void test1() {
        def headers = new HttpHeaders()
        def testVo = parseJson(this.mockMvc.perform(post('/test').headers(headers)
                .content(toJson(testRequest())))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andDo(document("testrest"))
                .andReturn())

        def name = testVo.name

    }


    def parseJson(MvcResult result) {
        return jsonSlurper.parse(result.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray())
    }

    def testRequest() {
        return [
                name: "ankit"
        ]
    }


}
```

Below is screenshot i am getting compilation error in `index.adoc` file:

[image: compilation error index.adocs]

Below is my controller class:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<TestVO> createFee(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestBody TestVO testVO) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(testVO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring REST Docs will only generate snippets if you have written some tests that use it. Have you done that? If you have and you can see the tests being run by Maven but they're not generating the expected snippets, can you share some information about them please?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Please find test case in edited question

Comment: The error shows that your IDE doesn't know about the `snippets` attribute. That should be set by the `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` extension that you have configured in your pom. Does it work when built on the command line? Perhaps you could turn the parts of your app that you have shared thus far into a [/help/mcve] minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson When i build using command prompt, `generated-snippet` folder not creating. But when i open existing spring restdocs project, that project create `generate-snippet` folder

Comment: **The error shows that your IDE doesn't know about the snippets attribute**
Because `generate-snippet` folder not created. If snippet folder created then this compilation issue will resolve.

Comment: **classes,generated-docs,generated-sources,generated-test-sources,maven-archiver,maven-status,surefire-reports,test-classes** these are folder created when run `mvn clean install`

Comment: I'm happy to continue trying to help you, but I'll need a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to be able to do so.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Please find github repository for code:  https://github.com/ankit45621/springrestdocs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong document object in Testcase. Use below:

`.andDo(document)` in place of `.andDo(document("testrest"))`